# how to make NSManagedObjectContext dirty (hasChanges = YES) Manually

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, ios4, ios5

the problem is:
while setting transient undefined attribute in `-(void)didSave` metod after first `save:` does not make context dirty in iOS 4.3 (Simulator), but makes it dirty in iOS 5.0 Simulator.

I need the same behaviour in iOS 4.3.

So - what is the cheapest way to make context dirty between 2 `(BOOL)save:` calls.

Once again - in iOS 5 setting transient attribute in `-(void)didSave` makes context dirty, but on ios 4.3 not.

and more - I need to make all objects that were changed in `didSave` method "dirty"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried subclassing NSManagedObjectContext and returning true for the hasChanges property or similar?